# Modify css of progress content in default opc

Tags: css, billing, onepage-checkout

I want to modify the css of the checkout progress panel. When the customer completes the steps, his content is shown in the panel. At the moment every entry is plain text on same background. I want to display odd and even tags with different backgrounds.

I can't find no output html in source code. I think the right html file would be `billing.hmtl` and this the relevant line of code:

`<dd class="complete">
    <address><?php echo $this->getBilling()->format('html') ?></address>
</dd>`

But where can I change the output of that call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the billing html template address. You can find it in Admin > System > Configuration > Customer Configuration > Address Templates > HTML.
For adding additional html tags with CSS classes, changing just the configuration may be enough.

```
1. Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Progress::getBilling()
2. return $this->getQuote()->getBillingAddress();
3. Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address extends Mage_Customer_Model_Address_Abstract
4. Mage_Customer_Model_Address_Abstract::format($type)
renderer is:
5. Mage_Customer_Block_Address_Renderer_Default
6. In function render there is: new Varien_Filter_Template();
```

If just adding CSS classes in the configuration above won't be enough than you can add your own placeholders and other logic directly in your class that extends Varien_Filter_Template. But you'll need to rewrite Mage_Customer_Block_Address_Renderer_Default too, to replace with MyNamespace_Filter_Template (in lib dir).

Or use the event:

```
 Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_address_format', array('type' => $formatType, 'address' => $this));
```

from Mage_Customer_Model_Address_Abstract::format().
I don't know if it's possible without too many rewrites - you could change the type from html to your own.
And in the observer function you may want to be sure you're in the right controller (checkout) or action.

Comment: worked like a charm, thanks. Magento could be so easy, if you knew where to change things...